# wp_dropdown_categories custom taxonomy view all

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I've got a custom post type called 'projects'.

Attached to this is a custom taxonomy called 'type'.

On both the 'projects' and 'type' archive pages, I have a dropdown to filter the loop results by taxonomy term (type).

These work fine, except the 'view all' option at the top, which when clicked does not submit the form, so does nothing.

Any ideas?

Code in archive-projects.php & taxonomy-type.php…

```
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'show_option_all'    => 'All',
                        'hide_empty'         => 0,
                        'class'              => 'selectpicker',
                        'taxonomy'           => 'type',
                        'hide_if_empty'      => false,
                        'value_field'        => 'slug',
                    ); ?>

                    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
                        function onCatChange() {
                            if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != -1 ) {
                                location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/projects/' ) ); ?>/"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
                            }
                        }
                        dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
                    </script>
```

functions.php…

```
  $projectLabels = array(
      'name' => _x('Projects', 'post type general name'),
      'singular_name' => _x('All Projects', 'post type singular name'),
      'all_items' => 'All Projects',
      'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Project'),
      'add_new_item' => __("Add New Project"),
      'edit_item' => __("Edit Project"),
      'new_item' => __("New Project"),
      'view_item' => __("View Project"),
      'search_items' => __("Search Projects"),
      'not_found' =>  __('No Project(s) found'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Project(s) found in Trash'),
      'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $projectArgs = array(
      'labels' => $projectLabels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => false ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'menu_position' => null,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','revisions','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-building',
      'has_archive' => true
    );
    register_post_type('projects',$projectArgs);



    // taxonomy
    add_action( 'init', 'create_project_tax' );

    function create_project_tax() {
        register_taxonomy(
            'type',
            'projects',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Types' ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'projects' ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you ruled out all external factors, e.g. Have you tried printing to the console to check the values, are you getting any javascript errors, have you disabled plugins, etc?

Comment: tried without plugins, no Js errors. haven't tried printing to the console - not quite sure how to do that!

Comment: You can display debugging messages in the browsers console tab using the JS `console.log('your message here');` Try add messages before & after setting location.href to make sure the code is getting triggered, check the selected option value, and see if location.href is getting ignored (i.e. the message displays) or fails and gets no further (no message), e.g. `console.log("selected option:"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value); location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/projects/' ) ); ?>/"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value; console.log("after redirect");`

Comment: Okay so i tried:
`location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/projects/' ) ); ?>/"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
console.log("selected option");`

and the message shows just before the page changes to whatever you selected.

I also added a `'show_option_none'  => 'Show…'` to the `$args` and found that clicking this "null" option then clicking the 'All' option does take you to where you want to go, so the problem is that clicking the same option as already selected will not trigger the link, and the default option on page load is always the top one - 'All'

Comment: SO I need to set it so that clicking the already selected/active option in the dropdown also triggers the form submit…

Comment: Yes, its default behaviour that selecting the active option doesn't trigger an event. I assumed you were selecting it when something else was already active :) I'm not really sure of a good away around that, because it is the default behaviour.

Comment: I managed to get the behaviour I was after by adding `show_option_none`, so my `$args` looks like…
`'show_option_none' => 'All projects',
'option_none_value' => '',
'show_option_all'    => 'Choose a category…',`
Adding the option_none value as blank and setting the `location.href` in the javascript to `home_url( '/projects/' )` takes you back to the custom post type archive page.

Bit of a hack but does what it needs to!

Cheers for your help